# How did Susan understand who Joe Black was?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, meet-joe-black

At the ending of *Meet Joe Black* - how did *Susan* understand that *Joe Black* was *Death*, and that the guy she met at the coffee shop had actually died, and has now returned, by being swapped with *Death*?

Comment: I haven't seen the film in a few years, but if my memory serves me right, there isn't any real exposition (dialogue) given for how Susan knows and/or if she truly understands or believes it's Death or not, but I think there are expressions in her face/body language through Death's lack of knowledge that leads her to this conclusion/notable difference from the man she met, but I think it just serves as another "mystery" that exists that film chooses to leave ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

The [film's script](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Meet-Joe-Black.html) gives us some insight into what's going on. In short, the 'Young Man' has different mannerisms and expressions than the Joe that she's come to know. She recognises those.

> **SUSAN:** *Joe...?*
>
> He smiles quizzically, hasn't quite heard her, stands right in front
> of her, loose, smiling, disoriented and yet so appealing.  They are
> riveted on each other, uneasy and yet close.
>
> **SUSAN (cont'd):** *You're here...*
>
> He is trying to get his bearings.
>
> **JOE** -- *You bet.*
>
> Something about him makes Susan slightly tentative.
>
> **SUSAN:** *Where did you go?*
>
> Joe shrugs, scratches his head endearingly, uncertain of time and
> place.
>
> **JOE:** *I don't know -- y'know, I don't know -- it's all blurred up and hazy.  And would y'know what I mean if I said I don't think it's
> worth figuring out?*
>
> Some realization is dawning on Susan, it renders her lightheaded.
>
> **JOE (cont'd):** *...But now I'm back.*
>
> Susan regards Joe intently, searching his face for an answer.
>
> **SUSAN (gently):** *That's it?*
>
> **JOE:** *Well, I don't know what else to say. It's a helluva party --*
>
> **SUSAN:** *You think so?*
>
> **JOE:** *Yeah...and you're the prettier thing here.*
>
> **Susan blinks, a long silence, she touches the sleeve of his jacket,
> now her hand traces the outline of his face, she regards him intently
> and the dilemma she has been struggling with the last moments fades
> away.**
>
> **Susan slowly realizes this is the Young Man. She is shaken, a sudden
> intake of breath.**

It's not really clear here what Susan knows (or thinks she knows), but she evidently understands that something weird has happened, like waking up from a dream. In the end they pledge to work it out between them.

> **SUSAN:** *...We know so little about each other.*
>
> **YOUNG MAN:** *But we've got time.*